# I would like to know which sentence is correct

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, present-tense

Which of these sentences is correct?

> Could you please help me with your name

or

> May I please know your name

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are grammatically correct (lacking only a question mark at the end).

But your question appears to be more about their suitability than their construction.

There are numerous contexts in which a person's name is sought, whether by an official, a teacher, an acquaintance, a bank ...and so on.

Depending on how formal or informal the inquiry is, different constructions will typically be used. Some examples are:

> May I know your name (formal)
>   Could you tell me your name  (fairly formal)
>   What's your name  (informal)
>   What are you called  (informal)
>   Please let me know your name (formal)
>   What is the name please (at hotel or restaurant check in)